# Proving if A and B are matrices such that A, B, and AB are normal, then BA is also normal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

If A and B are matrices such that A, B, and AB are normal, then BA is also normal.

I've seen this statement around, although I've only seen the site/publication/etc... state that it was proven by Wiegmann, but nobody actually gives the proof. Could somebody help me wrap my head around why this is true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proof as taken from this paper: Kaplansky, Irving Products of normal operators. Duke Math. J. 20, (1953). 257-260. This paper is also contained in 'Selected Papers and Other Writings of Irving Kaplansky'. It is supposed to be proven originally by Wiegmann, but I do not have access to this paper.

**Theorem 1:** Assume $A$ and $AB$ are normal. If $B$ commutes with $A^*A$ then $BA$ is normal.

*Proof:* Take the polar decomposition of $A$, $A=UP$, $U$ unitary, $P=P^*$. Since $A$ is normal it follows
$$
AA^* = UPP^*U^* = A^*A = P^*P,
$$
hence $UP^2 = P^2U$, which implies that $U$ and $P$ commute.

As $B$ commutes with $A^*A$ it also commutes with $P=(A^*A)^{1/2}$.

This implies
$$
U^*ABU = U^*UPBU = PBU = BPU = BA,
$$
hence $BA$ is unitary equivalent to a normal matrix, and thus is normal itself.

**Theorem 2:** Assume $A$, $B$, $AB$ normal. Then $B$ commutes with $A^*A$.

*Proof:* Set $C:=BA^*A-A^*AB= [B,A^*A]$ where $[C,D]=CD-DC$ denotes the commutator of two matrices $C$ and $D$.

Then
$$
C^*C=(A^*AB^*-B^*A^*A)(BA^*A-A^*AB) = A^*AB^*BA^*A - A^*AB^*A^*AB
-B^*A^*ABA^*A  +B^*A^*AA^*AB.
$$
Now, by normality of $AB$ and $A$ we obtain 
$$
B^*A^*AA^*AB- A^*AB^*A^*AB = (B^*A^*)(AA^*AB)- (A^*AAB)(B^*A^*)= [B^*A^*,AA^*AB].
$$
Since 
$$
A^*AB^*BA^*A-B^*A^*ABA^*A = A^*AB^*BA^*A-ABB^*A^*A^*A= (A^*)(AB^*BA^*A)-(AB^*BA^*A)(A^*) = [A^*,AB^*BA^*A].
$$
This proves
$$
C^*C = [B^*A^*,AA^*AB] + [A^*,AB^*BA^*A].
$$
Since the trace of commutators is zero due to $tr(CD)=tr(DC)$, it follows
$tr(C^*C)=0$, hence $C=0$, and $B$ commutes with $A^*A$.

---

Theorem 1 + 2 now prove the claim.

Answer (score 8):

There is a simpler proof for this statement (see Problem 42 in Section 2.5 of [Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC) by Horn and Johnson).

You [already know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030016/show-that-a-in-mathbbc-n-is-normal-iff-traa-sum-i-1n-lambda) that a matrix 
$$A \text{ is normal if and only if } \mathrm{tr}(A^*A)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i(A)|^2,$$
where $\lambda_i(A)$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are normal and $\mathrm{tr}(XY)=\mathrm{tr}(YX)$ for square $X$ and $Y$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{tr}[(AB)^*(AB)]&=\mathrm{tr}(B^*A^*AB)=\mathrm{tr}(B^*AA^*B)\\&=\mathrm{tr}(A^*BB^*A)=\mathrm{tr}(A^*B^*BA)=\mathrm{tr}[(BA)^*(BA)].
\end{split}
$$
So we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i(BA)|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i(AB)|^2=\mathrm{tr}[(AB)^*(AB)]=\mathrm{tr}[(BA)^*(BA)],
$$
where the first equality follows from the fact that the eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are equal ($AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomials) and the second from the normality of $AB$.
Hence $BA$ is normal.

Comment: Though $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$, note that the arbitrary permutations are not allowed in general: $tr(ABC) \neq tr(ACB)$.

Comment: @K.Huang Of course, I did not claim that. The cyclic property is used only in the place where the equations splits. The equalities around that point follow from the normality of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You are right! Thanks