# Proving if A and B are bounded operators such that A, B, and AB are normal, then BA is also normal.

Tags: functional-analysis

From [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028413/proving-if-a-and-b-are-matrices-such-that-a-b-and-ab-are-normal-then-ba-is-al) we know that if $A$ and $B$ are matrices such that $A, B$, and $AB$ are normal, then $BA$ is also normal.

I would like to know if this property holds in a more general way:

if $A$ and $B$ are bounded operators in a Hilbert space, such that $A, B$, and $AB$ are normal, then $BA$ is also normal

Comment: In order to show that $(AB)^*AB=AB(AB)^*$ it is enough to prove that $x=0$, where $x=(AB)^*AB-AB(AB)^*$.
Given the identity $\Vert x^*x\Vert =\Vert x\Vert ^2$, it is in turn enough to prove that $x^*x=0$, or even that   $xx^*x=0$.  When you expand
this out the resulting expression might be quite big but you will have plenty of opportunities to employ your hypothesis!

Comment: I apologize for the comment above since it does not seem to work.  I tried to follow this method and got nowhere.  I even tried proving that $xx^*xx^*=0$,  in the hope that the hypothesis could be used more often, to no avail.